# Implement search feature using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have implemented the search feature using JavaScript and Regex. Firstly, I converted the input string into tokens then searched for it in the target array.

This is the sample code.

```
const tokens = inputString
    .toLowerCase()
    .split(' ')
    .filter(function (token) {
      return token.trim() !== ''
    })

  const searchTermRegex = new RegExp(tokens.join(' '), 'gim')
   const filteredList = targetArray.filter(function (item) {
    return item.match(searchTermRegex)
  })
```

This code is running fine, only problem is it does not search if the words are present in random order.
For example, if target string is "scrape the data from pages", and I search for "data scrape" then it is not able to detect it.

What's the better solution for it?

Expected Output:  If at least a single word from the input is present in the target string, it should show that string in the final output.

Comment: you need to match both words or any one from `data`,`scrape`

Comment: `new RegExp(tokens.join('|'), 'gim')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's not clear whether your need both the words in your targeted result or either of them, there is an answer for either case therefore I'm adding solution if both words are need for which you'll need **positive lookaheads**, and it seems like your requirement is that you need to have both word complete in your inputString, that's why I've added **word boundaries** in the regex using **\b**, if that's not needed you can update the token mapper with this:

`(?=.*${token})`

Also I've refactored your code a little bit, hope that helps

```
const tokens = inputString
                .split(' ')
                .filter(Boolean)
                .map(token => `(?=.*\\b${token}\\b)`);
const searchTermRegex = new RegExp(tokens.join(''), 'gim');
const filteredList = targetArray.filter(item => item.match(searchTermRegex));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this. I think split not necessary

```js
const inputString = "scrape the data from pages"
const targetArray = ["data", "scrape"]


const filteredList = targetArray.every(function(item) {
  return  inputString.indexOf(item) > -1
})

console.log("matchStatus", filteredList)
```

OR Regex

```js
const inputString = "scrape the data from pages"
const targetArray = ["data", "scrape"]


const filteredList = new RegExp(targetArray.join('|'),'gim').test(inputString)

console.log("matchStatus", filteredList)
```